# how do i use object values as another objects keys in js?

Tags: javascript

Say i have this object:

```js
const element = {
    name: 'first_name',
    value: 'Joe Blow',
}
```

how do i use `element.name` as the key and `element.value` to construct another object?

for example, i've tried this:

```js
const data = {
    element.name: element.value,
}
```

above example does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it using es6 computed properties:

```js
const data = {
    [element.name]: element.value,
}
```